# Vuejs: Routes are accessible even after deleting a token

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authorization

I have a very strange behaviour when I log out from my app. Some inner links (from a user's panel, for example) are still accessible even after I logged out and deleted a token. And some links are not. Do you have any ideas how I can prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Generally with [a navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) that is applied globally and looks at the route meta data. Without any code it is impossible to tell why you see odd behaviour like that though.

Comment: Do you use guards? Maybe some code sample of your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by using axios interceptors. I check if the error status in 401 (Unauthorised) and push router to the login page.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
 if (error.response.status === 401) {
  config.token = null;
  router.push({ name: 'login' });
 }
if (error.response.status === 404) {
 router.push({ name: 'error' });
}
 return Promise.reject(error);
});
```